# get Mosquitto cpu and memory use

Tags: linux, mosquitto

I want to get the cpu and memory use of Mosquitto broker while publishing and subscribing to a topic. I execute this linux command: top -p PID, I get 0% for MEM and 0% or 3% for CPU and the most weired think that the process status is S (sleeping) but there is some clients that publish and subscribe to the broker.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but you may use [SYS Topics](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/SYS-Topics) to get runtime status of [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html).

> $SYS/broker/heap/current size The current size of the heap memory in
>   use by mosquitto. Note that this topic may be unavailable depending on
>   compile time options.
>
> $SYS/broker/heap/maximum size The largest amount of heap memory used
>   by mosquitto. Note that this topic may be unavailable depending on
>   compile time options.